# Validation field count in delimited data file

Tags: unix, awk

I have data files as below

```
123|123|123#456|456|456|456#789|789|789
```

here row delim is `#` and col delim is `|`

I want to put two validations i.e. to count number of rows `-vRS="#" 'END{print NR}'`

now for second validation where I need to count field count in each row and compare with some constant value `-F"|" '{print NF}'`

I need help in putting this logic in coding construct of `awk`.

expected output: row with more than 3 fields should get printed with row number.

```
2 : 456|456|456|456
```

Answer (score 3):

To print number of fields for every line:

```
awk -vRS=# -F\| '{print NF}' file
3
3
3
```

---

To test if every line has 3 fields:

```
awk -vRS=# -F\| -vC=3 '{print (NF==C?"yes":"no")}' file
yes
yes
yes
```

---

Some more testing:

```
awk -vRS=# -F\| -vC=3 'NF!=C {print "NR="NR,$0;f=1} END {print "Number of rows =",NR;print (!f?"All rows has "C" fields":"Some rows does not have "C" fields")}' t
NR=2 456|777|765|452
Number of rows = 3
Some rows does not have 3 fields
```

This will print number of rows, and tell if all rows has 3 fields or not.

If you does not like to get hit on `1` and `2` fields, change test to `NF>C`

Comment: @fedorqui It did have a flaw, fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -vRS=# -F\| 'NF>3{print NR, ":", $0}' File
```

Sets `RS(record seperator to #)`, and `Field seperator to |` firstly.

Within the awk script, checks if `NF(number of fields) > 3`. If yes, then print `NR(row number)`, `:` and `the row itself($0)`